# What is the velocity of an ejected electron in lithium when subjected to UV radiation?

Tags: homework, quantum-chemistry

If UV radiation strikes an atom of **lithium** with one electron in its lowest allowed energy state with enough energy to eject the electron from orbit, what is the electron's velocity upon ejection? The wavelength is **7.1 * 10^-9 meters**.

If this was hydrogen, I would use the fact that the energy of the radiation is the sum of the binding energy and kinetic energy of the electron, but the conditions are for lithium. How would I solve this problem given that it's lithium and not hydrogen?

Answer (score 1):

The energy is still the sum of the kinetic and the binding energy. The only difference is how you calculate the binding energy, but you could just look it up